# how to get full directory path of a file or folder using php

Tags: php

I use this code to list the folders and files I have inside of a certain directory, but I need the full path of each one of them.
eg. `C:\Users\houdi\Desktop\03012018134338-0001.pdf`

```
 <?php
 function listFolderFiles($dir){
 $ffs = scandir($dir);

 unset($ffs[array_search('.', $ffs, true)]);
 unset($ffs[array_search('..', $ffs, true)]);

 // prevent empty ordered elements
 if (count($ffs) < 1)
    return;

 echo '<ol>';
 foreach($ffs as $ff){
     echo '<li>'.$ff;
     if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
     echo '</li>';
 }
 echo '</ol>';
 }

 listFolderFiles('C:\Users\hsaoudi\Desktop\Haithem');

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code to get the full path
I hope it work for you..

```
<?php
      $FullPath = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
      //include_once "$FullPath/stack/db.php";
      echo "$FullPath/stack/db.php";
?>
```

If above not working then try:

```
<?php
      $dir = dirname(__FILE__);
      echo $dir;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function for get fullpath of file,

```
<?php
echo realpath("your file name");
?>
```